# Execution order of Main Tasks and Micro Tasks with strange output

Tags: javascript

I just need an explanation about the strange output, not for the order.

```
console.log('script start');

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('setTimeout');
}, 0);

Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  console.log('promise1');
}).then(function() {
  console.log('promise2');
});

console.log('script end');
```

The output on Chrome

[image]

The output on Firefox and IE are same

[image]

So, why `undefined` appear? And why there is a difference between Chrome and IE/Firefox?

Comment: What part of the output is strange to you?

Comment: `undefined` is what `console.log('script end')` returns (try logging anything, and you’ll notice `undefined` show up underneath it). The Chrome console probably implements it with promises (maybe to support REPL await) so it ends up in a microtask, and the Firefox and IE ones don’t.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined because of `console.log` because it does not return anything so you get this undefined.You can observe this same situation when you write

```
 var a = 10
 //undefined
```

If you remove your `console.log()` from your code then you will see `undefined` just vanished

On other hand if you add something it will produce the sum so we will get no `undefined`

```
 10+2
 12
```

Take this example:

```
 function add(){
    return 12
 }
 //undefined
 add()
 12
```

In above code when we define a function it will reproduce nothing so we get `undefined` and when we call it so it return something and we get just answer no `undefined`

I have checked you code on IE and Chrome i am getting same output.if you still want to see how this program works you can go here and try to run it. It will show you event loop, call stack and full code execution.

http://latentflip.com/loupe/